# AutoFixture: PropertyData and heterogeneous parameters

Tags: c#, xunit.net, autofixture

Given the following test:

```
[Theory]
[PropertyData("GetValidInputForDb")]
public void GivenValidInputShouldOutputCorrectResult(
    string patientId
    , string patientFirstName
)
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();          

    var sut = fixture.Create<HtmlOutputBuilder>();

    sut.DoSomething();
    // More code
}
```

I want to encapsulate fixture creation in its own class, something akin to:

```
[Theory]
[CustomPropertyData("GetValidInputForDb")]
public void GivenValidInputShouldOutputCorrectResult(
    string patientId
    , string patientFirstName
    , HtmlOutputBuilder sut
)
{
    sut.DoSomething();
    // More code
}
```

The problem is that I'm using `PropertyData` and the latter is supplying two input parameters. The fact that I'm then trying to automatically create my fixture as a parameter is causing an exception.

Here is the CustomPropertyData:

```
public class CustomPropertyDataAttribute : CompositeDataAttribute
{
    public CustomPropertyDataAttribute(string validInput)
        :base(new DataAttribute[]
            {
                new PropertyDataAttribute(validInput),
                new AutoDataAttribute(new Fixture()
                    .Customize(new HtmlOutpuBuilderTestConvention() )), 
            })
    {

    }
}
```

What are the options to resolve this?

Comment: How does the `CustomPropertyData` looks like?

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis I've updated the OP. I tried to write my code as per http://nikosbaxevanis.com/2012/07/27/composite-xunit-net-data-attributes/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply data to the `PropertyDataAttribute` as below:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetValidInputForDb 
{
    get
    {
        yield return new object[]
        {
            "123", 
            "abc"
        };
    }
}
```

The `patientId` value will be *123*, the `patientFirstName` value will be *abc* and the SUT value is going to be supplied automatically by AutoFixture.

The `CustomPropertyDataAttribute` looks good.

Comment: Ok let me go back to the drawing board because I pretty much did what you've suggested. However, I did get an exception. I'll try it again and try to gist it if need be. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like it's either something wrong with the `HtmlOutpuBuilderTestConvention` or perhaps a question targeting the `PropertyDataAttribute` at xUnit.net forums.. To test it replace `HtmlOutputBuilder` with `IDisposable` and `HtmlOutpuBuilderTestConvention` with `AutoMoqCustomization` you can see that the test executes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've still got to try you suggestion but I'll get back to you once I've figured out what's wrong.

Comment: Your answer is correct as the issue I was having is related to xUnit rather than AutoFixture.