# AutoFixture CompositeDataAttribute does not work with PropertyDataAttribute

Tags: c#, xunit.net, autofixture

I'm trying to create `AutoPropertyDataAttribute` based on `CompositeDataAttribute` from this example [AutoFixture: PropertyData and heterogeneous parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841414/autofixture-propertydata-and-heterogeneous-parameters).

It works with single set of parameters, but fails with more sets of parameters. Here is code:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> NumericSequence
{
    get
    {
        yield return new object[] {1};
        //yield return new object[] {2};
    }
}

[Theory]
[AutoPropertyData("NumericSequence")]
public void Test(int? p1, int? p2, int? p3)
{
    Assert.NotNull(p1);
    Assert.NotNull(p2);
}

public class AutoPropertyDataAttribute : CompositeDataAttribute
{
    public AutoPropertyDataAttribute(string propertyName)
        : base(
              new DataAttribute[] { 
                  new PropertyDataAttribute(propertyName), 
                  new AutoDataAttribute()
              })
    {
    }
}
```

Trying to uncomment the second `yield` will break test with message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Expected 2 parameters, got 1 parameters
   at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Xunit.CompositeDataAttribute.<GetData>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Xunit.Extensions.TheoryAttribute.<GetData>d__7.MoveNext()
   at Xunit.Extensions.TheoryAttribute.EnumerateTestCommands(IMethodInfo method)
```

Same happens with `ClassDataAttribute`

Comment: What is the role of the second `yield`? It provides the data for `p2` or it provides the data for `p1` on the 2nd run?

Comment: @nikos it provides the data for p1 on the 2nd run

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. It *might* be a bug in the `CompositeDataAttribute` class defined in AutoFixture. However this class is programmed against the base of all data theories, the `DataAttribute` class, so it *looks* like a violation of the LSP in `PropertyData` and `ClassDataAttribute` classes defined in xUnit.net. I will keep this thread updated.

Comment: FWIW, there is no LSP violation in xUnit.net `PropertyData` or `ClassData`. I have provided an answer below. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What actually happens**

The `NumericSequence` `[PropertyData]` defines *two* iterations.

The *composition* of `NumericSequence` `[PropertyData]` with `[AutoData]` assumes that there is enough data on *each iteration*.

However, the actual composition is:

```
1st iteration:  [PropertyData], [AutoData]

2nd iteration:  [PropertyData], [n/a]
```

That's why in the 2nd iteration you eventually run out of data.

**Composition**

The `CompositeDataAttribute` respects the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in a sense that it is programmed against the *base* of all data theories, the `DataAttribute` class.

*(That is, there is no assumption that all attributes are composed with `[AutoData]` at the end.)*

For that reason, it can't simply jump from the 2nd iteration to the 1st iteration and grab some `[AutoData]` values – that would break the LSP.

**What you *could* do**

Make the actual composition look like:

```
1st iteration:  [PropertyData], [AutoData]

2nd iteration:  [PropertyData], [AutoData]
```

By defining two properties:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> FirstPropertyData { get { 
    yield return new object[] { 1 }; } }

public static IEnumerable<object[]> OtherPropertyData { get { 
    yield return new object[] { 9 }; } }
```

And then, the original test can be written as:

```
[Theory]
[AutoPropertyData("FirstPropertyData")]
[AutoPropertyData("OtherPropertyData")]
public void Test(int n1, int n2, int n3)
{
}
```

The test executes twice and `n1` is always supplied by `[PropertyData]` while `n2` and `n3` are always supplied by `[AutoData]`.

Comment: I don't understand this explanation. I would think that CompositeAutoData was supposed to use the composed attributes as data sources in order to build what's basically a table (two-dimensional matrix) of values. As long as there's enough data to fill all cells in the table, it should be able to work. Thus, while CompositeAutoData can't expect the last attribute to be an AutoData, it still ought to ask to see if it *can* provide the requested values. Basically, I'd expect the first composed attribute to determine the number of *rows*, and the rest to fill in the missing cells.

Comment: What I am trying to explain is that on the 2nd iteration the current example runs out of data.. The composite can't just jump from the 2nd iteration to the 1st iteration and supply data.. If that's the case then all the tests in [this](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture.xUnit.net.UnitTest/CompositeDataAttributeInsufficientDataTest.cs) class should fail.

Comment: While my answer describes the current behavior, the two-dimensional matrix idea sounds great! But then, we would end up selecting data randomly after some point.

Comment: This answer applies for xUnit2 and `MemberData` as well.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue and decided to implement a custom DataAttribute to solve the problem. I couldn't use either attribute as a base class (reasons below) so I just took the things I needed from the source of each. Thank you OSS :)

Things to note:

- I wanted to change the semantics slightly so that I had the option of yielding single objects rather than arrays. Just makes code look neater for single-object parameters. This meant I couldn't use `PropertyDataAttribute` as a base class
- The fixture needs to be created every time a new set of parameters is generated. This meant I couldn't use `AutoDataAttribute` as a base class

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/alexfoxgill/03c781d3bd4222c88daa)

Or inline source below:

```
public class AutoPropertyDataAttribute : DataAttribute
{
    private readonly string _propertyName;
    private readonly Func<IFixture> _createFixture;

    public AutoPropertyDataAttribute(string propertyName)
        : this(propertyName, () => new Fixture())
    { }

    protected AutoPropertyDataAttribute(string propertyName, Func<IFixture> createFixture)
    {
        _propertyName = propertyName;
        _createFixture = createFixture;
    }

    public Type PropertyHost { get; set; }

    private IEnumerable<object[]> GetAllParameterObjects(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        var type = PropertyHost ?? methodUnderTest.DeclaringType;
        var property = type.GetProperty(_propertyName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Could not find public static property {0} on {1}", _propertyName, type.FullName));
        var obj = property.GetValue(null, null);
        if (obj == null)
            return null;

        var enumerable = obj as IEnumerable<object[]>;
        if (enumerable != null)
            return enumerable;

        var singleEnumerable = obj as IEnumerable<object>;
        if (singleEnumerable != null)
            return singleEnumerable.Select(x => new[] {x});

        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Property {0} on {1} did not return IEnumerable<object[]>", _propertyName, type.FullName));
    }

    private object[] GetObjects(object[] parameterized, ParameterInfo[] parameters, IFixture fixture)
    {
        var result = new object[parameters.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < parameterized.Length)
                result[i] = parameterized[i];
            else
                result[i] = CustomizeAndCreate(fixture, parameters[i]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private object CustomizeAndCreate(IFixture fixture, ParameterInfo p)
    {
        var customizations = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (CustomizeAttribute), false)
            .OfType<CustomizeAttribute>()
            .Select(attr => attr.GetCustomization(p));

        foreach (var c in customizations)
        {
            fixture.Customize(c);
        }

        var context = new SpecimenContext(fixture);
        return context.Resolve(p);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodUnderTest, Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
        foreach (var values in GetAllParameterObjects(methodUnderTest))
        {
            yield return GetObjects(values, methodUnderTest.GetParameters(), _createFixture());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you. I made some tweaks so that I could provide multiple class properties and get a combination of parameters (e.g. first property with 3 cases and second property with 2 cases will generate 6 different test cases). This is useful when you already have a paramaterized test method and want to test two different implementations. Also, I combined it with `AutoNSubstituteCustomization` to get mocking support.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can restructure the `AutoPropertyDataAttribute` a bit and use the `CompositeDataAttribute` internally, rather than deriving from it.  Derive from the `PropertyDataAttribute` instead:

```
public class AutoPropertyDataAttribute : PropertyDataAttribute
{
    public AutoPropertyDataAttribute(string propertyName)
            : base(propertyName)
    {
    }
```

Then override the `GetData` method to loop over the values returned by the `PropertyDataAttribute`, and leverage AutoFixture's `InlineAutoData`(which derives from `CompositeDataAttribute`) to fill in the rest of the parameters:

```
    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodUnderTest, Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
        foreach (var values in base.GetData(methodUnderTest, parameterTypes))
        {
            // The params returned by the base class are the first m params, 
            // and the rest of the params can be satisfied by AutoFixture using
            // its InlineAutoDataAttribute class.
            var iada = new InlineAutoDataAttribute(values);
            foreach (var parameters in iada.GetData(methodUnderTest, parameterTypes))
                yield return parameters;
        }
    }
```

The outer loop iterates over the values returned by the `PropertyData` (each iteration is a row, with some of the cells filled in).  The inner loop fills in the remaining cells.

It's not the prettiest thing, but it seems to work.  I like Mark's idea to have AutoFixture try to fill in the remaining cells.  One less piece of glue code to write :)

Hope this helps,
Jeff.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore with xunit.net 2.0 since `PropertyDataAttribute` has been deprecated and its replacement `MemberDataAttribute` is sealed. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852608/autofixture-compositedataattribute-does-not-work-with-propertydataattribute/28767887#28767887) worked for me.