# How to combine PropertyData and AutoNSubstituteData attributes in xunit/autofixture?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, xunit.net, autofixture, nsubstitute

I am using the `[AutoNSubstituteData]` attribute, which was posted here:

[AutoFixture, xUnit.net, and Auto Mocking](http://nikosbaxevanis.com/blog/2012/07/31/autofixture-xunit-dot-net-and-auto-mocking/)

I would like to combine this with the `[PropertyData("")]` attribute from xunit extensions.

This is my test:

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> InvalidInvariant
{
    get
    {
        yield return new string[] { null };
        yield return new [] { string.Empty };
        yield return new [] { " " };
    }
}

[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData, PropertyData("InvalidInvariant")]
public void TestThatGuardsAreTriggeredWhenConnectionStringArgumentIsInvalid(
    IDeal deal,
    IDbConnection conn,
    IDb db,
    ISender sender,
    string invalidConnString,
    string query)
{
    deal.Init.Group.Returns(Group.A);
    deal.Aggr.Group.Returns(Group.A);
    deal.Product.Commodity.Returns(Product.Commodity.E);

    var sut = new Handler(db, sender);
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => 
        sut.HandleDeal(deal, conn, invalidConnString, query));
}
```

Is there a way to combine these attributes or to get the desired functionality (mock everything, except for `invalidConnstring`, which should be filled with the property-data)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

**Option 1** - Using [AutoFixture.Xunit](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit) and the CompositeDataAttribute class:

```
internal class AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    internal AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization()))
    {
    }
}

internal class AutoNSubstitutePropertyDataAttribute : CompositeDataAttribute
{
    internal AutoNSubstitutePropertyDataAttribute(string propertyName)
        : base(
            new DataAttribute[] { 
                new PropertyDataAttribute(propertyName), 
                new AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute() })
    {
    }
}
```

Define the test cases as below:

```
public class Scenario
{
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> InvalidInvariantCase1
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new string[] { null };
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> InvalidInvariantCase2
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new string[] { string.Empty };
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> InvalidInvariantCase3
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new string[] { " " };
        }
    }
}
```

Then declare the parameterized test as:

```
public class Scenarios
{
    [Theory]
    [AutoNSubstitutePropertyData("InvalidInvariantCase1")]
    [AutoNSubstitutePropertyData("InvalidInvariantCase2")]
    [AutoNSubstitutePropertyData("InvalidInvariantCase3")]
    public void AParameterizedTest(
        string invalidConnString,
        IDeal deal,
        IDbConnection conn,
        IDb db,
        ISender sender,
        string query)
    {
    }
}
```

Please note that the parameterized parameter `invalidConnString` have to be [declared before the other parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852608/autofixture-compositedataattribute-does-not-work-with-propertydataattribute/18930198#18930198).

**Option 2** - Using [Exude](https://github.com/GreanTech/Exude):

```
public class Scenario
{
    public void AParameterizedTest(
        IDeal deal,
        IDbConnection conn,
        IDb db,
        ISender sender,
        string invalidConnString,
        string query)
    {
    }

    [FirstClassTests]
    public static TestCase<Scenario>[] RunAParameterizedTest()
    {
        var testCases = new [] 
        {
            new 
            {
                invalidConnString = (string)null
            },
            new
            {
                invalidConnString = string.Empty
            },
            new
            {
                invalidConnString = " "
            }
        };

        var fixture = new Fixture()
            .Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());

        return testCases
            .Select(tc =>
                new TestCase<Scenario>(
                    s => s.AParameterizedTest(
                        fixture.Create<IDeal>(),
                        fixture.Create<IDbConnection>(),
                        fixture.Create<IDb>(),
                        fixture.Create<ISender>(),
                        tc.invalidConnString,
                        fixture.Create<string>())))
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Actually, that's nearly what @MarkSeemann wrote, but in code :) Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

The `[Theory]` attribute works by looking for one or more 'data source attributes'; for example

- `[InlineData]`
- `[PropertyData]`
- `[ClassData]`
- etc.

The `[AutoData]` attribute is just another such attribute, as is your derived `[AutoNSubstituteData]` attribute.

It's possible to add more than one 'data source attribute' to the same `[Theory]`, as witnessed by the idiomatic use of the `[InlineData]` attribute:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("foo")]
[InlineData("bar")]
[InlineData("baz")]
public void MyTest(string text)
```

This produces *three* test cases.

It's also possible to combine `[PropertyData]` and `[AutoData]`, but it **probably doesn't do what you want it to do**. This:

```
[Theory]
[AutoNSubstituteData]
[PropertyData("InvalidInvariant")]
public void MyTest(/* parameters go here */)
```

will result in **1 + n** test cases:

- 1 test case from `[AutoNSubstituteData]`
- n test cases from the `InvalidInvariant` property

These two attributes know nothing about each other, so you can't combine them in the sense that they're aware of each other.

However, when you're implementing a property, you can write whatever code you'd like, including using a `Fixture` instance, so why not just do this?

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> InvalidInvariant
{
    get
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new MyConventions());
        // use fixture to yield values...,
        // using the occasional hard-coded test value
    }
}
```

Another option is to use derive from the [`InlineAutoDataAttribute`](http://nikosbaxevanis.com/blog/2011/08/25/combining-data-theories-in-autofixture-dot-xunit-extension/), which would enable you to write your test cases like this:

```
[Theory]
[MyInlineAutoData("foo")]
[MyInlineAutoData("bar")]
[MyInlineAutoData("baz")]
public void MyTest(string text, string someOtherText, int number, Guid id)
```

This would cause the first argument (`text`) to be populated with the constants from the attributes, while the remaining parameters are populated by AutoFixture.

Theoretically, you may also be able to combine the `[AutoData]` and `[PropertyData]` attributes using the `CompositeDataAttribute`, but it [may not work the way you'd like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18852608/126014).

Finally, you could consider using [Exude](https://github.com/GreanTech/Exude) for true first-class parameterized tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an `AutoPropertyDataAttribute` that combines xUnit's `PropertyDataAttribute` with AutoFixture's `AutoDataAttribute`. I posted it as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28767887/1860652).

In your case you will need to inherit from the attribute in the same way as you would from an `AutoDataAttribute`, with the exception that you pass a fixture creation function instead of an instance:

```
public class AutoNSubPropertyDataAttribute : AutoPropertyDataAttribute
{
    public AutoNSubPropertyDataAttribute(string propertyName)
        : base(propertyName, () => new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```